# Create copy of sheet and change the owner?

Tags: google-sheets, copy, file-ownership

I have a googlesheet in a shared folder that I want the user I share with to be able to submit a copy of it. The problem is I need the owner of the new created sheet to be me so I can edit it. The script I am trying is below so it creates a new googlesheet with its name based of a cell to the shared folder. I then get the id of the new sheet created but I can't seem to get the setOwner. argument to work on the new sheet created. Is it possible to change the owner of the new sheet from the original sheets script?

```
function SubmitSheet() {
    var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder ID");
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    const name = sheet.getRange("C7").getValue();
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById("Orginal file Id");
    var newFile = file.makeCopy(name, destFolder);
    var newId = newFile.getId();
    var new_owner = 'my email';
    Logger.log(newId);
    DriveApp.getFileById(newId).addEditor(new_owner).setOwner(new_owner);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. There is a spreadsheet in a shared Folder; you are the owner of the spreadsheet and you want to create a copy of the spreadsheet to share with your colleague AND you want to be the owner of that "shared copy" So rather than add yourself as an Editor (`.addEditor(new_owner)`) why not just add your colleague as an Editor. You retain ownership but your colleague can edit the spreadsheet as planned.